# Where can I find file system path specifications

Tags: parsing, boost, path, specifications

I am looking for one, or more likely a handful of, specification(s) that outline the elements of a file system path. What do I mean by that? Mainly, I am looking to implement a "simple" (read, air-quotes) parser specification to verify the path that I am reading is valid. Ultimately, I want to parse a delimited list of said paths, i.e. that I might read from an environment variable.

I'm looking at the *DOS*/*Windows* specification at first, but I expect that *Linux*, *UNC*, etc, would be acceptable variations as well.

Now, the brain dead thing I could do is simply take the string and *tokenize* on the *delimiter*, then perhaps hand off the tokens to something like `boost::filesystem::path` or `std::filesystem::path`. Perhaps that would be sufficient?

I know there are such specifications for things like email addresses, Uri's, and this sort of thing. That's the kind of technical specification I am interested in.

My target language is *C++*. Failing the above, I am leveraging the *Boost Spirit Qi* for the parser grammar. I am expecting the grammar should express things like valid characters, prohibit invalid characters at strategic times, that sort of thing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Posix standard defines Pathname in Section 3.271 of [Chapter 3, Base Definitions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html). But it's really simple:

- Pathnames can contain any character except NUL.
- A system may specify a maximum length and if it specifies it, it may enforce the limit.
- The path can be decomposed as follows:

  - Optional leading `/` characters
  - Any number of path components each consisting of one or more characters other than `/` or NUL, separated by one or more `/` characters.
  - Optional trailing `/` characters.
    This decomposition does not make any path string invalid. It merely defines how it is parsed.
- It is possible (but not required) that pathnames starting with exactly two slashes have some special significance on a particular system. Other than that, multiple consecutive slashes are not significant (but are always permitted). So a pathnam starting with a single slash is considered the same as the same series of components starting with three or more slashes.

Answer (score 0):

I found [Microsoft docs](http://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/FileIO/naming-a-file#naming-conventions) concerning naming conventions and such, which more or less outlines the issue, at least as far as Windows is concerned. I also found this [outline of representations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Representations_of_paths_by_operating_system_and_shell).

I am focused on Windows at the moment. Open questions are naming conventions concerning `drive_letter`, `server`, `sharename`, `drive_spec`, and `physical_device`. Although, I somewhat gather that `drive_spec` is the same as `drive_letter`? Not positive, however.

Otherwise, I am collating as much about the invalid sets of characters as I am the allowable characters, their sequences, parts, extensions, reserved names, etc.